# How to find the force needed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, equilibrium

[image]

To keep the system in equilibrium, the F<sub>g</sub> should equal F<sub>Buoyant</sub> + F<sub>Magnetic</sub>. However, I'm having trouble seeing how the F<sub>Magnetic</sub> would push the tube upwards. We're using conventional current, and the current is flowing clockwise, so when I use the right hand rule, I see that the force is pointing downwards. Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely right, the magnetic force is downards. The thing is that you want this force to be exactly the difference between the weight and the buoyance force of the wire so that it won't sink or float from its current position. If the force were upwards then the problem would make no sense as the buoyancy is greater than the weight!

Comment: If you need further advice with the answer to the question, ask me here!

Comment: Thank you! In that case would the answer be 2.45?

Comment: You are exactly right.